# Color distortion after coming out only from automatic suspend

Tags: drivers, suspend

The display colors are totally distorted after resuming from suspension. This **does not happen** if I manually suspend but if the PC suspends itself after the specified time on settings on Ubuntu 18.04, when I resume the colors are totally broken. If I restart gnome-shell (Alt + F2 - r) everything goes back to normal. What is the difference between manually suspend and automatic suspension? Is it possible to restart gnome-shell automatically everytime the PC comes back from automatic suspend?

I installed oibaf/graphics-drivers but I only get a black screen with a random underscore on boot. radeon.modeset=0 is not a viable option. What can I do?

System info:

- Caicos [Radeon HD 6450/7450/8450 / R5 230 OEM]
- Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
- Ubuntu 18.04 (default installation)